# I declar the Variable with a function but get "fopen(): Filename cannot be empty"

Tags: php, file-handling

So i want to open a file and declare the path of this file over a function..
in this function i Upload the file and return the path of it..

```
$file = upload(); <- where i declare the variable

function upload(){
  //UPLOAD
  if (isset($_FILES['datei'])) {
    ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
    $upload_folder = getcwd().'/uploads/'; //Das Upload-Verzeichnis
    $filename = pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['datei']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    //Überprüfung der Dateiendung
    $allowed_extensions = array('csv');
    if(!in_array($extension, $allowed_extensions)) {
      die("Ungültige Dateiendung. Nur csv-Dateien sind erlaubt");
    }

    //Pfad zum Upload
    $new_path = $upload_folder.$filename.'.'.$extension;

    //Neuer Dateiname falls die Datei bereits existiert
    if(file_exists($new_path)) { //Falls Datei existiert, hänge eine Zahl an den Dateinamen
      $id = 1;
      do {
        $new_path = $upload_folder.$filename.'_'.$id.'.'.$extension;
        $id++;
      } while(file_exists($new_path));
    }

    //Alles okay, verschiebe Datei an neuen Pfad
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['datei']['tmp_name'], $new_path);
    echo 'Datei erfolgreich hochgeladen';
    return $new_path;
  }
}
```

and this is where i want to open the file

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r", 1)) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
        rowformating($data);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

EDIT:

it seems the error only comes when i check the file for errors. if i execute the file and upload smth "$file" ist filled with the path of the uploaded file

Comment: have you print the value of $file ?

Comment: @PrinceGautam yes it contains the right directory

Comment: Can you do a `file_get_contents` on $file ? Do you have rights for reading on the file ?

Comment: @NockaRocka: can you put a var_dump just before the if() and see the contents of $file?